# Android how to get album cover using FQL

Tags: android, json, api

I'm trying to get a list of albums with their covers photos, to display in my app. Here's what i do :

```
    Bundle params1 = new Bundle();

    JSONObject jsonFQL = new JSONObject();
    jsonFQL.put("query1", "SELECT aid, name, cover_pid FROM album WHERE owner=" + myId);
    jsonFQL.put("query2", "SELECT src_small from photo WHERE pid IN (SELECT cover_pid FROM #query1)");


    params1.putString("method", "fql.query");
    params1.putString("query", jsonFQL.toString());

    Utility.mAsyncRunner.request(null, params1,
            new AlbumsRequestListener());
```

But the response of my request is :

```
{"error_code":601,"error_msg":"Parser error: unexpected '{' at position 0.","request_args":[{"key":"access_token","value":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"},{"key":"query","value":"{\"query1\":\"SELECT aid, name, cover_pid FROM album WHERE owner=100000000000000001\",\"query2\":\"SELECT src_small from photo WHERE pid IN (SELECT cover_pid FROM #query1)\"}"},{"key":"method","value":"fql.query"},{"key":"format","value":"json"}]}
```

What am i doing wrong ? Thank you!

Comment: it looks like your parameter is supposed to be called "query", according to the error message

Comment: @njzk2 thank you, i've made that change but it's stil not working. I've updated the error message.

Comment: fixed id, quotes were needed in pid = '<pid value>'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed id, quotes were needed in pid = ''